# Why is there "with conn" in socket library example?

Tags: python, sockets

The python socket documentation gives this example : But why is `with conn:`necessary?

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Comment: *"Support for the context manager protocol was added. Exiting the context manager is equivalent to calling `close()`."* - https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects

Comment: @SoccerFan, I doubt you have any more idea who downvoted (or why) than I do. Someone with a diamond next to their name is very unlikely to be playing the kind of games you're accusing deceze of -- moderators are _elected_, and people notice how they treat others and consider it in casting votes.

Comment: (if I were to downvote this, personally, it would be because "why did someone write this code this way?" is a call for speculation, as opposed to a question about a _specific technical problem_ -- though I haven't done so, because what you clearly intended by the question was more along the lines of "what does using a socket as a context manager do in Python?", which is clear and specific).

Answer (score 1):

Use of a context manager is not "necessary". It is however very convenient and leads to more robust code.

This is because the `__exit__` method of the underlying class will be implicitly invoked as the *with* block terminates. That method can close sockets, file handles etc and generally release resources in a "clean" manner rather than leaving it up to the programmer.